# inner html from d.properties from 2 different data sources (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have two side-by-side d3 choropleth maps, both drawn from the same geojson but representing different data from different years, current and 2014.

I load the data from two separate years:

```
var currentMap = d3.map();
var map2014 = d3.map();

d3.queue()

.defer(d3.csv, "data/overdoses_2018_updated.csv", function(d) { 
    if (isNaN(d.DrugOverdoseMortalityRate)) {
        console.log('nan')
    } else {
        currentMap.set(d.FIPS, +d.DrugOverdoseMortalityRate); 
    }

})
.defer(d3.csv, "data/overdoses_2014_updated.csv", function(e) { 
    if (isNaN(e.DrugOverdoseMortalityRate)) {
        console.log('nan')
    } else {
        map2014.set(e.FIPS, +e.DrugOverdoseMortalityRate); 
    }

})
  .await(ready);
```

And successfully render the map for current year-

```
    //GeoPath
  var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
    .projection( albersProjection );



    d3.select("svg.current").selectAll("path")
    .data( CaliforniaCountiesOverdoses.features )
    .enter()
    .append( "path" )
    .attr( "d", geoPath )
        .attr("class","counties")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { 
            var value = currentMap.get(d.properties.ID);
            return (value != 0 ? current_color(value) : "grey");  
})
    // setting popup based on current data
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {         
            countyDiv .html('<br/>' + d.properties.NAME + '<br/>' + d.properties.DrugOverdo + ' overdoses per 10,000')  
            })
```

Now, I do the same for year 2014:

```
 d3.select("svg.map2014").selectAll("path")
    .data( CaliforniaCountiesOverdoses.features )
    .enter()
    .append( "path" )
    .attr( "d", geoPath )
        .attr("class","counties-2014")

        .attr("fill", function(e) { 
            var value2014 = map2014.get(e.properties.ID);
            return (value2014 != 0 ? current_color(value2014) : "grey");  
})
     // trying to set popup based on 2014 data
    .on("mouseover", function(e) {        
            county2014Div .html('<br/>' + e.properties.NAME + '<br/>' + e.properties.DrugOverdo + ' overdoses per 10,000')
```

Everything works perfectly - the county fill color is reflecting 2014 data, but the html being fed into the county2014Div is not the 2014 data, it's the current data still.  How do I get this to read d.properties from the 2014 data source as opposed to current?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the data as found in `CaliforniaCountiesOverdoses.features`.

Like you do it in the `fill()` look up the value based on the ID of the `path`.

```
d3.select("svg.map2014").selectAll("path")
    .data( CaliforniaCountiesOverdoses.features )
    .enter()
    .append( "path" )
    .attr( "d", geoPath )
    .attr("class","counties-2014")
    .attr("fill", function(e) { 
        var value2014 = map2014.get(e.properties.ID);
        return (value2014 != 0 ? current_color(value2014) : "grey");  
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(e) {        
        var value2014 = map2014.get(e.properties.ID);
        county2014Div .html('<br/>' + e.properties.NAME + '<br/>' + value2014 + ' overdoses per 10,000');
```

Your code can be simplified a lot by removing all the code duplication.

Comment: thanks!  This worked perfectly but I'm trying to figure out why.  Why do you need to declare the value2014 variable again in the mouseover function?   And what exactly is map2014.get(e.properties.ID) pointing to?  Thanks again!

Comment: javascript has function scope. you need to use the ID of the path and look for the data as found in the 2014 json data, map2014 is build during the loading phase with this id=>properties mapping